# Arithmetic overflow error for type varchar

Tags: sql-server

I have a variable `OUTL_New_$` = `4055166.88`. I am using below sql code to store the value in a table.

```
'$ '+substring(parsename(convert(varchar,convert(money,cast(OUTL_New_$ as int)),1),2),1,13)
```

However, it is showing below error:

```
Arithmetic overflow error for type varchar, value = 4055166.880000
```

Can someone help me to understand why this error?

Answer (score 1):

If you declare @OUTL_New_$ as NVARCHAR,
then you must cast it as a decimal(18,3) , and not as a INT:

<kbd>**[`Open query in a New Page`](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/edit/398759)**</kbd>

Comment: This should be comment. Nice to see linking with <kbd> :)

Comment: My bad. There was something else that was causing the error.

Comment: I am not able to post anymore questions due to 3 down votes to this question. How do I improve this question?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT '$ ' + SUBSTRING(PARSENAME(CONVERT(VARCHAR, CONVERT(MONEY, CAST(4055166.88 AS INT)), 1), 2), 1, 13)

SELECT FORMAT(CAST(4055166.88 AS INT), '$ ###,##,####')
```

result -

```
$ 4,055,166
```

Comment: My bad. There was something else that was causing the error. I am deleting this question.

Comment: by the way, if you use sql server 2012 - check FORMAT function

Comment: I am not able to post anymore questions due to 3 down votes to this question. How do I improve this question?